# How can I diagnose, debug MinGW-get GUI (guimain.exe) crashing?

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, gnu, mingw-w64

Initially, I wanted to install the updated MinGW packages using the MinGW-get GUI, but it crashes when I choose "Mark All Upgrades" from the 'Installation' drop-down menu (whether I update the catalogue or not).

Now, I want to figure out why `guimain.exe` is crashing.

[image: A screen capture of the MinGW-get GUI crashing on my computer]

How can I diagnose and debug this persistent problem? I am vaguely familiar with GDB, but I've never used it. I am not committed to using the Visual Studio debugger.

I assume I need to use some ancillary binaries or debug libraries in the latest MinGW installer branch here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get/mingw-get-0.6.2-beta-20131004-1/

Can anyone please guide me? Any assistance or suggested reading is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to debug this, rather than just posting a bug report or upgrading your MinGW?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to fix the bug myself rather than merely reporting it. But you are correct that I would like to upgrade my MinGW libraries as well (which was my original intention after all).

Comment: As developer and maintainer of mingw-get, I really appreciate your willingness to participate in debugging this issue, which BTW,  I am unable to reproduce myself. I do wonder if this is the most appropriate forum for discussing the issue, rather than on a MinGW.org specific ML or bug tracker? Unfortunately, the published builds of mingw-get have been stripped of debug symbols, and it will be three or four months before I can find the time to effectively guide you through the process of deploying a debug enabled build, (which surely will not support the VS debugger in any case).

Comment: Is this confined to the mingw-get GUI? Can you upgrade from the command line, using the `mingw-get update`, followed by `mingw-get upgrade` commands? (You need to ensure that `C:\MinGW\bin`, or wherever else you may have installed mingw-get.exe, is in your PATH).

Comment: It is not confined to the MinGW-get GUI. The `mingw-get update`, followed by `mingw-get upgrade` commands similarly result in this (apparently) null pointer crash.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is in mingw-get-0.dll, which is shared by GUI and CLI clients; that's where we need to focus attention, and debugging through the CLI may prove more fruitful.  Nonetheless, I still won't be able to give it any attention over the next few months. FTR, are you on 32 or 64 bit Windows? And what version?

Comment: @KeithMarshall, I'm not the asker, but I'm having issues on 64-bit Windows 7 SP1 (Professional). The program crashes when trying to mark (whether for install or upgrade, but not removal) any __bin__ class item under __MinGW Compiler Suite__, except `mingw32-binutils`, and including `mingw32-base` (which isn't listed under Compiler Suite). Other classes are fine, other categories are fine. I would also like to help when a debuggable version is available.

Comment: If it's interesting: Marking mingw-developer-toolkit for upgrade makes it hang for a few seconds, but it ends up going through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happen to have the same issue. The GDB way to debug this:

`gdb mingw-get.exe`

`r upgrade` (run with argument upgrade)

GDB will automatically stop at a SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) signal, that's what happens for me.

`bt` (get a backtrace)
For me this resulted in a huge backtrace, filled with calls to:

`#5013 0x6f9cdda4 in mingw-get-0!_ZN14pkgXmlDocument19ResolveDependenciesEP10pkgXmlNodeP13pkgActionItem () from c:\MinGW\libexec\mingw-get\mingw-get-0.dll`

It looks like a recursion problem that quickly filled up the call stack.
Note that function name is mangled, and we don't know the line number. This is the best you can do without debugging symbols. If you have the debugging symbols, GDBs output becomes more useful. For most Linux-style packages, you can get the debugging symbols in a -dbg package named similiarly to the stripped binary package. However I don't see a debug package for mingw32-mingw-get in the listing.

Comment: Thank you @kcghost. This was the kind of introductory answer I was seeking. I will try this out.

Comment: @MavaddatJavid faced the same issue. Did you solved it?

Comment: I have not solved it. I did not see a very convenient way of getting the debugging symbols, nor have I looked at the source code. I was hoping the developer @keith-marshall would see it :).

Answer (score 12):

For those who are experiencing the crash on attempting to upgrade packages.. try running it in recursive mode..

```
mingw-get upgrade --recursive
```

that appeared to force an upgrade for me..

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Solved my crashing upgrade on Win7_x64.